# I have a Phaser project but when I try to load an image appear this error

Tags: javascript, web

[image]

Hello, I have a Phaser project but when I try to load an image, the console show me this error, I try to reinstall Phaser but I don`t have results

My code

```
function preload() {
    this.load.image("pajaro", "./assets/bird.png");
    console.log('cargando');}
function create() {
    this.add.image(50, 100, "pajaro")
    console.log('cargado');}
```

Comment: `the console show me this error` - what error?

Comment: Oh, the 404 in the pretty picture! ... that means the file isn't found

Comment: Yes... Where can I see all files, I mean, the folder where are all images?

Comment: I don't know, it's your project